# LINQ - Query with distinct/GroupBy on multiple properties problem

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, distinct, distinct-values

I have some data stored in an EntitySet of my domainContext where I want to select out just parts of it. Problem is that I'm getting all the CageNames - and not just the "New" ones with the highest date.

This is the data:

SiteId  CageId  CageName    Date
1   ,1  ,Lot1       ,'2011-05-05'
1   ,1  ,LotNew     ,'2011-05-06'
1   ,2  ,Lot1       ,'2011-05-05'
1   ,2  ,LotNew     ,'2011-05-06'
1   ,3  ,Lot1       ,'2011-05-05'
1   ,3  ,LotNew     ,'2011-05-06'

So for each CageId listed I want to return the CageName on the record that has the highest date.
My code trying to do this is here:

```
Dim CageName As Array

CageName = DomainContext.SiteCageDatas.Where(Function(h) h.SiteId = SiteId) _
      .Select(Function(x) x.CageName).Distinct.ToArray()
```

But this just gives me all CageNames.. Any idea how I should fix this, I guess maybe using groupby or something?
Mind; I'm using VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DomainContext.SiteCageDatas.GroupBy(Function(x) x.CageId).Select(Function(x) x.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Date).LastOrDefault()).Where(Function(x) x IsNot Nothing).Select(Function(x) x.CageName).ToArray()
```

Comment: Helpful, but doesnt work.. I forgot to mention that I probably need to group on the siteid also - because I can have many sites listed like the above one. And I want only the newest CageName for each siteid/cageid.. Any other tips?

Comment: Could you give me an example of correct output for your test data?

Comment: And also, I would suggest to create a stored procedure to do such task

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this now, but that returns nothing :(

```
 CageName = DomainContext.SiteCageDatas.GroupBy(Function(a) New With {a.SiteId, a.CageId}).Select(Function(a) a.OrderBy(Function(b) b.Date).LastOrDefault()).Where(Function(x) x.SiteId = SiteId).Select(Function(x) x.CageName).ToArray()
```